# Xcode crashing on a specific project

Tags: xcode, xcode8

When I'm trying to open a specific project on `Xcode` it's crashing with this error message (part of it):

```
Process:               Xcode [729]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               8.1 (11544)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-11544000000000000~4
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       819397000
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [729]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-11-06 18:39:39.261 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.1 (16B2555)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        E3BEFD49-5451-DC5B-81D3-2BD8B1F4987F


Time Awake Since Boot: 140 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 8B62
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSRangeException): *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]
UserInfo: (null)
Hints:
```

When I try to open another project everything is fine, it's just this specific project.

I've tried to restart my Mac and it still crashes.

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting re-open project error alert? If yes then dont re-open. Instead close and quit Xcode and restart your project. Also if you are using two versions of Xcode and both are open then close and quit both before opening anything.

Comment: @Sharpkits I've updated my question with a screenshot of the crash alert. and I don't have 2 versions of Xcode running

Comment: @matt What do you mean? Is it Apple's bug? And how to send them? And is this the only way to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @matt So there is no way to fix it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Do one thing, clear off/delete all the **derived data** for Xcode and then open your project. That should fix the issue.

Also to report a bug to Apple you can simply go to https://bugreporter.apple.com/ and login with apple credentials and and they'd get back to you in like couple of days.

Also for derived data do the following:
You can go to `File > Workspace Settings` if you are in a **workspace environment** or `File > Project Settings` for a **regular project environment**.

Then click over the little grey arrow under **Derived data** section and select your project folder to delete it.

Comment: Where can I find the `derived data`?

Comment: Xcode is crashing, so I don't have access to the `File` menu. Any other way to get there?

Comment: you can go to this path "/Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" by opening a `finder window`, click on `go` -> `go to folder` and enter in the above address with **userName** replaced by your local mac username and that should take you to derived data folder.

Comment: Glad that worked.. Cheers!!
Don't forget to upvote :)

Comment: in my case, adding above process, I should remove pod-related files. here is my shell script `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` `rm Podfile.lock` `rm -rf Pods` `rm -rf *.xcworkspace` `pod install` `open *.xcworkspace`

Comment: If it keep happening when you build and you have cleaned derived data, you can also do a regular clean and it might help.

Comment: Thanks, thats save my day

Comment: I was having the same crash on XCode 11.2.1 . I went on to "Show package contents" of the ".xcworkspace" workspace directory and deleted "xcuserdata" folder. This resolved the crash for me.

Answer (score 15):

Nothing work for me. I delete my `.xcworkspace` and regenerate `.xcworkspace` by `pod install` and work for me.

Comment: Very good! The only things that worked for me. I just went in show package of the xxx.xcodeproj, delete the xcworkspace, and launch the xcodeproj, and ta daa!

Comment: Works after deleting `.xcworkspace` and `pod install`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

To fix this problem:

open a Finder window and navigate to your project
right-click on the .xcodeproj file (it’s a package actually)
select Show Package Contents
a new window appears
delete a folder called xcuserdata
Now open your project again in Xcode and it should work. Your workspace will be reset, bringing a very small amount of happiness and tranquility back into your life.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was resolved by:

"I was able to get unblocked by deleting project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata in my project"

Detailed discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/7zh9wg/xcode_crashes_on_startup/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is a bit of a dated question but I just spent half my afternoon with the same issue in 9.1.... Basically if you have icloud drive enabled on your computer, you will wreck havok on xcode...not sure why / how but it just does....I moved all of my dev projects out of documents and it now works beautifully. Cheers and good luck