# I use Xcode8.3 to open the old project, Xcode will crash. Xcode Version 8.3 (8E162)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I use Xcode8.3 to open the old project, Xcode will crash. Hope that God has a good solution. Thank you! I used Xcode Version 8.3 (8E162)! The following is the crash log[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5kd5.jpg)

```
Date/Time:             2017-05-24 10:55:13.864 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.5 (16F73)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        E6D015C9-5D5B-8165-3DED-5FA9DEE16B80

Sleep/Wake UUID:       D9402094-DE3A-4B1E-9D9E-4DC22BEB3839

Time Awake Since Boot: 93000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        20  Dispatch queue: shared-compile-command-queue :: NSOperation 0x7fd3ef034ae0 (QOS: DEFAULT)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 8E162
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-12169/IDEFoundation/Diagnostic/IDEDiagnosticActivityLogMessage.m:298
Details:  (fixItString) should not be nil.
Object:   <IDEDiagnosticFixItItem: 0x7fd3eebb6150>
Method:   -initWithFixItString:replacementLocation:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd3ebf12fd0>{number = 34, name = (null)}
Hints:   

Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[IDEDiagnosticFixItItem initWithFixItString:replacementLocation:] (in IDEFoundation)
  4   -[IDEClangDiagnosticActivityLogMessage initWithDiagnostic:timestamp:pathMap:workingDirectory:documentURL:] (in IDEFoundation)
  5   -[IDEClangDiagnosticActivityLogMessage initWithDiagnostic:timestamp:pathMap:workingDirectory:] (in IDEFoundation)
  6   _XCMessageForDiagnostic (in DevToolsCore)
  7   XCGenerateDiagnosticsFromFile (in DevToolsCore)
  8   -[XCClangResultsPostprocessor generateDiagnosticsFromFile:logSectionRecorder:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9   -[XCClangResultsPostprocessor postprocessResultsForCommandInvocation:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10   -[XCWorkQueueCommandSubprocessInvocation handleEndOfOutput] (in DevToolsCore)
 11   -[XCWorkQueueCommandLocalSubprocessInvocation handleEndOfOutput] (in DevToolsCore)
 12   -[XCWorkQueueCommandLocalSubprocessInvocation handleOutputFileDescriptorActivity] (in DevToolsCore)
 13   -[Xcode3BuildTask main] (in DevToolsCore)
 14   -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)
 15   __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 16   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 17   _dispatch_queue_serial_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 18   _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 19   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 20   _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 21   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 22   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
```

**I have solved the problem, hope to encounter problems after the friend, check the path of the library used.**

Comment: Does creating a new project work ok though?

Comment: Create a new project no problem, that is, open the old project to run, it will crash

Comment: I also got this problem sometimes, if open with older XCode, it will be fine, you can download it in [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)

Comment: Have you cleared the derived data?  See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451843/xcode-crashing-on-a-specific-project

Comment: What is your OS version?

Comment: macOS version 10.12.5

Comment: I   cleared the derived data，But still crash   ，Online solution I have tried, cleared the derived data and Delete xcuserdata folder are no use！